# Retrieving the new contents of a control in its On Change event handler

Tags: string, vba, ms-access, recordset

```
Public Function EditUpdate()
Dim rstEditAddress As DAO.Recordset
Dim Svalue, EditedAddressLine1 As Variant

Svalue = Me.lstBoxCompanyName.Value

EditAddressValue = "SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE CompanyID =  " & Svalue
Set rstEditAddress = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(EditAddressValue)

EditedAddressLine1 = Me.txtbxAddressLine1.Value

With rstEditAddress
 .Edit
    .Fields("AddressLine1") = EditedAddressLine1
    .Fields("AddressLine2") = NewAddressLine2
    .Fields("AddressLine3") = NewAddressLine3
    .Fields("Town") = NewTown
 .Update
End With

End Function
```

I have a text box conveniently named `txtbxAddressLine1`. Using the `On Change` event in Access, the event calls this function and should go through the procedure of updating the record in the table with the 'edited' data. However the value in `EditedAddressLine1` never seems to change! It always has the value of which was originally in the table.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: do a `Debug.Print EditedAddressLine1` before the `With ...` block. See if the value stores in `EditedAddressLine1` is the actual value you're expecting to be overriden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `Change` event handler for a control, read its `Text` not `Value` property to get the new data:

```
EditedAddressLine1 = Me.txtbxAddressLine1.Text
```